# Proof that field extensions of degree 3 over $K$ with $\mathrm{char}(K) \neq 3$ are separable

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> My question is how one can prove, for all field extensions $K \subset L$ with $[L:K]=3,  $ char($K$) $\not=3$, that $L$ is separable over $K$.

I understand [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/38525) proof with 2 in stead of 3. I imagine a similar proof, but with the Cardano formula instead of the $abc$ formula. If so, isn't there a nicer proof?

I'm also wondering whether this holds for all primes $p$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $[L:K]=p$ and ${\rm char}\,K\ne p$ with $p$ prime. Show the following:

- For all $\alpha\in L$ either $\alpha\in K$ or $K[\alpha]=K(\alpha)=L$.
- If $\alpha\in L\setminus K$ then $p(x):={\rm minpoly}_{\alpha,K}(x)\in K[x]$ has degree $p$.
- If $p(x)$ has repeated factors then $\gcd(p(x),p'(x))\ne1$ in $K[x]$.
- By irreducibility, the only monic divisors of $p(x)$ are $1$ and $p(x)$.
- For all $f(x)\in K[x]$, either $f(x)=0$ or $\deg f'(x)<\deg f(x)$.
- $\gcd(p(x),p'(x))=p(x)$ is not possible unless $p'(x)=0$.
- For all $f(x)\in K[x]$, $f'(x)=0$ implies $({\rm char}\,K)\mid \deg f$.

Comment: Isn't your answer assuming that a primitive extension is separable iff the minimal polynomial of the primitive element is separable? I think to prove this you would need the characterization of separability as $L/K$ separable iff $\overline{K} \otimes_K L$ is reduced.

Comment: We see the result we want immediately upon noting that $\overline{K} \otimes_K L \cong \overline{K}[x]/(p(x))$ where $p$ is the minimal polynomial of the primitive element.

Comment: @BenjaLim My answer is assuming the definition of a separable field extension is "such that for every $\alpha\in L$ the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$ is separable (i.e. has distinct roots)" (Wikipedia).

Answer (score 3):

Fix an arbitrary minimal polynomial of $L/K$. It is of the form $x^3 + bx^2 + cx +d$. The derivative of this poly is $3x^2 + 2bx + c$. The extension is separable iff this derivative $\neq 0$, which is the case since ${\rm char}(K)\ne3$. Same method for the general case of $[L:K] = p \neq {\rm char}(K)$. QED